# create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-oauth

I am authenticating using email instead of username and i trying to add google authentication everything working fine but this is the error i'm getting:

```
File "/home/tboss/Desktop/environment/liveimages/backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_django/storage.py", line 79, in create_user
user = cls.user_model().objects.create_user(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'
```

user model:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
      def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
          if not email:
             raise ValueError('user must have email address')
          now = timezone.now()
          email = self.normalize_email(email)
          user = self.model(
                  email=email,
                  is_staff=is_staff,
                  is_active=True,
                  is_superuser=is_superuser,
                  last_login=now,
                  date_joined=now,
                  **extra_fields
                   )
         user.set_password(password)
         user.save(using=self._db)
         return user
     def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
         return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

     def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
         user=self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
         user.save(using=self._db)
         return user

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
      email = models.EmailField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
      First_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)
      Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)
      is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)
      is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default = False)
      is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
      last_login = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)
      date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

      USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
      EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
      REQUIRED_FIELD = []

     objects = UserManager()

     def get_absolute_url(self):
         return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
```

Also suggest me how can i integrate with react

Comment: My guess is you try to create some account using Google Auth?
You might want to have a look over Django All Auth or other lib specialized in such a matter: Your users do not "actually" need a password as tokens are given by oAuth provider

Comment: i'm using social django library

Comment: i have updated the error its lookalike trying to create user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your log says: `create_user` excepts a password, which is not provided by your auth method.
Following changes should do the trick:

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
      def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
          if not email:
             raise ValueError('user must have email address')
          now = timezone.now()
          email = self.normalize_email(email)
          user = self.model(
                  email=email,
                  is_staff=is_staff,
                  is_active=True,
                  is_superuser=is_superuser,
                  last_login=now,
                  date_joined=now,
                  **extra_fields
                   )
        # We check if password has been given
        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
         user.save(using=self._db)
         return user

     #We change following functions signature to allow "No password"
     def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):

         return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

     def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
         user=self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
         user.save(using=self._db)
         return user
```

Comment: it working but oauth doesn't provide password then how the user will be created

Comment: any idea how can i integrate with react using drf

Comment: User will be created without password, and Authentication will be handled with relevant configured auth_backend.
Regarding react, as your pipeline initiate using a specific url per backend, I do really see what you require